# Bitcoin alert service if price dips or rises by a percentage base?

Tags: price-volatility, alert-system

Is there a Bitcoin alert service that monitors the price and alerts the user when price dips or rises by a percentage base? Say I want to monitor the btc price if it rises by 5% and have it email me.

Comment: Voting to leave this open. See https://bitcoin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/534/is-a-does-x-exist-type-question-a-product-recommendation

Comment: This question is attracting link-only answers, and should be closed in my opinion. I've looked at the meta-link in the comment above; it doesn't convince me to leave it open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [coinzalert.com](http://coinzalert.com) to monitor the Bitcoin and altcoin market.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used it personally, but I have a lot of good things of the Bitcoin Paranoid app. It's supposed to alert you on price changes.

Here's the bitcointalk thread: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=178391.0

Answer (score 1):

Currently I'm using vertfolio https://vertfolio.com, it’s new but simple and easy to use, they have alerts based on the percent of the change ( daily and hourly ).

Answer (score 1):

Try https://www.kryptolabs.io its for Facebook Messenger pretty neat and of course the other ones mentioned here.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Cryptocurrency Alerting](https://cryptocurrencyalerting.com/). It has percentage price alerting, but it also has alerts for when coins get added to new exchanges, wallet transaction monitoring, and bitcoin mempool monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty, but I would recommend [Blockfolio](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blockfolio.blockfolio&hl=en), an Android app. You get the notification on the phone itself but it supports tons of coins and different exchanges to pick from.

On top of that it has charts and news (but are non-obtrusive if you don't need them).

Answer (score 0):

I created [Coindera](https://coindera.com) just for that. Some features:

- Price Point Alerts - when the BTC_USD buy price hits $10,000 alert me
- Percentage Change Alerts - when BTC_USD buy price increase more than 5% within 5 minutes alert me
- Regular Updates - every 30 minutes send me the price of BTC_USD
- 30+ markets
- 11k coins

Comment: Are you associated with the above site? If so, you must disclose your affiliation, or it is considered spam.

Comment: I said ... "I created" then Coindera so pretty clear that I created it ... no?

Comment: Indeed, my apologies, I somehow missed that!

Comment: All good no worries :)

Answer (score -1):

I use for cryptocurrency price alerts [Crypto Alert](https://crypto-alerting.com/crypto-price-alert/). Here you can specify both the specific price and the percentage change (By the way, there is a cool affiliate program here)